# Is there a way to see TQDM progress bars while using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-lab, tqdm

By default, PySpark (v3.3.2) is printing progress logs to my jupyter notebook.  It is overwriting the TQDM logs that I would to see to keep progress of the estimated computation time.

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

start_date = "2010-01-01"
end_date = "2010-12-01"

weeks = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq='W-MON')
weeks = [str(i)[:10] for i in weeks]

for week in tqdm(weeks):
   df = spark.read.parquet(some_file_path)
   df = df.groupBy([col1, col2]).agg(F.sum(col1)).toPandas()
```

Currently seeing this progress bar

`[Stage 701:=======================================>                (7 + 2) / 10]`

which has replaced the progress bar I would like to see

`9%|▉         | 12/127 [15:47<2:06:02, 65.76s/it]`

Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying `file=sys.stdout` to `tqdm` solved the issue for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

start_date = "2010-01-01"
end_date = "2010-12-01"

weeks = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq='W-MON')
weeks = [str(i)[:10] for i in weeks]

for week in tqdm(weeks, file=sys.stdout):
   df = spark.read.parquet(some_file_path)
   df = df.groupBy([col1, col2]).agg(F.sum(col1)).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable any prints to stdout by redirecting it to null file and then seting it back to previous stream. Here is sample code:

```py
prev_stdout = sys.stdout
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')

for x in tqdm(range(100)):
    sys.stdout = devnull

    print('test') # do your stuff here

    sys.stdout = prev_stdout

devnull.close()
```

Result (no `test` printed):

```
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:02<00:00, 49.78it/s]
```

Comment: While this works, the error I'm receiving is coming from pyspark, which is overriding TQDM.  Is there a way to shut off this pyspark output?

Comment: Did you try to override `sys.stderr` similarly as `sys.stdout` in above example?